# Is it legal to design an open source AHB master?

Tags: arm, legal, open-source, amba, ahb

Is it legal for open source cores to be compatible with the AMBA specification?

Comment: What does the license say?

Comment: Even downloading the documentation required a login and a license if I remember right.  There are some AXI interfaces already available at opencores that have not been taken down by arm, so that should tell you something.

Comment: It's legal in this country to design anything you want.  That's in the Constitution.  What you do with it after that is covered by the rule of law.